# Using Cmake's RelWithDebInfo as Default Build Type

Tags: c++, c++11, build, cmake

Are there any drawbacks to using RelWithDebInfo as the default build type when developing an application and for distributing it?

I thought about this after having a problem that occur in release mode but not in debug mode. And since then, I'm using RelWithDebInfo build type as default. I still get to debug the code and I haven't had any problems related to the build type.

Would this be a good way to prevent errors that does not occur in debug mode but occur release mode?

Comment: No, the good way is to throw away the bad code and write it over, properly. Just because it "appears" to work doesn't mean it's working, the bug is just hiding.

Comment: Of course we'll throw away the bad code I guess I didn't explain myself well. The debug mode problems occur because of the differences that release mode and debug mode have, like no optimization and such. So when you're developing on debug mode you do not know If your code has any release mode bugs until you build it in release mode which is usually when the project is finishing. So instead of waiting till the end to find the bug, we could just see it in development with RelWithDebInfo and still have the debugging perks.

Comment: I just noticed that you have mixed `RelWithDebugInfo` and `RelWithDebInfo` (the difference is `ug`). If you mistype the CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE, then it silently ignores what you type. You don't get any special flags, such as `-g -NDEBUG -O2`.

Comment: The correct spelling is `RelWithDebInfo` !

Comment: Thanks. I mistyped it in the title. But the spelling is correct in the question. ;-)

Comment: By default, CMake disables inlining partly under RelWithDebInfo under Visual Studio by using the flag `/Ob1` instead of `/Ob2` under Release. This can have a big effect on performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual drawbacks for debugging optimized builds apply.

In particular, the debugger may occasionally lie to you about what the values of variables are. Also it's usually not possible to inspect variables which have been optimized out, which typically affects function parameter and local variables.

What's arguably worse is, you don't get [asserts](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert). RelWithDebInfo sets the `NDEBUG` preprocessor flag which switches off assert and robs you of a powerful tool for diagnosing programming errors.

Of course there is nothing wrong with using RelWithDebInfo *as a default*, but you still should test all build types regularly. If you haven't done so already, set up a continuous integration system for your project that automatically runs all tests on all build types.